# How to open UNC path from run dialog box as a specific user?

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders, run-dialog, unc

When i use \computer\path in run box, folder opens directly without asking me which user I want to access the folder as...

have two computers A and B with administrators X and Y respectively, the shared folder exists on A and I have given X full permissions and Y has read only permissions on the shared folder. 
When I open this folder from computer Y's run dialog box it opens directly with read only permissions, how do I make it open as user X so that i have all permissions.

Comment: I have used double slash but it's only showing one above...

Answer (score 1):

Let's make the assumption you wish to get to `C:\temp` of Alice's Computer and just to make things clear:

- User A is `alice`
- User B is `john`

If you're logged in as Alice, you've started the `explorer` process as the logged in user, so you'll have full permissions (as dictated by user `X` in your example).

Now, if user `John` wants to access `\\share\path` whilst logged in as another user, there are 2 simple methods to achieve this.

**Using the Runas function**

> RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ]
>           /user: program

This can be translated to:

`runas.exe /user:localdomain\john explorer.exe`

This will run the process `explorer` as John, regardless as who is logged in (you could create a script in PowerShell to dictate this).

**Mapped Drives**

The next option is to simply attempt [Accessing a Windows share with a different username](https://superuser.com/questions/727944/accessing-a-windows-share-with-a-different-username)

Comment: Note you'd need to use the `runas.exe /user:domain\x explorer.exe C:\` from the run folder, if that wasn't clear enough.